# Search Binary Tree received when Search is wrong

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, binary-search-tree, singly-linked-list

Guys I really cannot handle. How am i supposed to solve this. I kept getting my root error it always mention that root is nullptr. Then, suddenly all my record of books gone/remove. I don't know how to manage this problem i kept changing using strcmp and without it but still. Same goes if I found the searched, it delete all my record of the books. Maybe you guys can provide me some error syntax that need to be fix and explaination of my error through coding. [This is the snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjQO9.png)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    char title[50], author[50], ISBN[50], pubDate[20], searchAuthor[50];
    struct node* left, * right;
};
struct node* delete_node(struct node* root, char deleteAuthor[]);
struct node* insert_node(struct node* root, char author[], char title[], char ISBN[], char pubDate[]);
struct node* FindMin(struct node*);
//struct node* search(struct node* root, char deleteAuthor[]);

void in_display(struct node* root);
void search(struct node* root, char searchAuthor[]);


void main()
{
    struct node* root = NULL;
    int ch, loop;
    char title[50], author[50], ISBN[50], pubDate[20], searchAuthor[50], deleteAuthor[50];
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tBinary Search Tree");
    printf("\n\t\t-- To stores a library of book records");
    printf("\n\t\t-- To search a library of book records");
    printf("\n\t\t-- To delete a library of book records");
    printf("\n\t\t-- To display a library of book records");
    printf("\n\t=========================================================\n");

    printf("\n\tState the number of book you need to input: ");
    scanf("%d", &loop);
    for (int c = 0; c < loop; c++) {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t--------Insert New Book--------");
        printf("\n\tEnter the author of the book: \t\t\t");
        scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", author);
        printf("\tEnter the title of the book: \t\t\t");
        scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", title);
        printf("\tKey in the ISBN code: \t\t\t\t");
        scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", ISBN);
        printf("\tEnter the Publication Date of the book: \t");
        scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", pubDate);
        root = insert_node(root, author, title, ISBN, pubDate);
    }
    printf("\t\t\t--------Insert New Book End--------\n\n");
    printf("\n\tPlease enter choice (1/2/3/4/5) based on the ....");
    do
    {
        //printf("\n\t1.\tInsert a new Boook Record");
        printf("\n\t1.\tDisplay all the Books record");
        printf("\n\t2.\tDelete a Book Record");
        printf("\n\t3.\tSearch a abook Record ");
        printf("\n\t4.\tExit");
        printf("\n\n\tEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch){
        case 1:
            printf("\n\t\t-----------------Library of Book Records-----------------\n");
            in_display(root);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\nEnter the author of the book to be deleted: \t");
            scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", deleteAuthor);
            root = delete_node(root, deleteAuthor);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\nEnter the author of the book to be searched: \t");
            scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", searchAuthor);
            search(root, searchAuthor);
            break;
        case 4:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default: printf("\n\tWrong Option\n");
        }
    } while (1);
}
struct node* insert_node(struct node* root, char author[], char title[], char ISBN[], char pubDate[])
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        strcpy(temp->author, author);
        strcpy(temp->title, title);
        strcpy(temp->ISBN, ISBN);
        strcpy(temp->pubDate, pubDate);
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    if (strcmp(author, root->author)<=0)
    {
        root->left = insert_node(root->left, author, title, ISBN, pubDate);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right = insert_node(root->right, author, title, ISBN, pubDate);
    }
    return root;
}
void in_display(struct node* root) {
    
    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    in_display(root->left);
    printf("\n\tAuthor Name \t\t- %s", root->author);
    printf("\n\tBook Title \t\t- %s", root->title);
    printf("\n\tISBN \t\t\t- %s", root->ISBN);
    printf("\n\tPublication Date \t- %s\n", root->pubDate);
    in_display(root->right);
}
struct node* delete_node(struct node* root, char deleteAuthor[]) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return root;
    }
    else if (strcmp(deleteAuthor, root->author) < 0) {
        root->left = delete_node(root->left, deleteAuthor);
        printf("\nBook Record Not Found\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(deleteAuthor, root->author) > 0) {
        root->right = delete_node(root->right, deleteAuthor);
        printf("\nBook Record Not Found\n");
    }
    else {
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
            free(root);
            root = NULL;
            printf("\nBook Record Successfully Deleted\n");
        }
        else if (root->left == NULL) {
            struct node* temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            free(temp);
            temp = NULL;
            printf("\nBook Record Successfully Deleted\n");
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL) {
            struct node* temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            free(temp);
            temp = NULL;
            printf("\nBook Record Successfully Deleted\n");
        }
        else {
            struct node* temp = root;
            root->left = FindMin(root);
            root->left->right = root->right;
            root = root->left;
            strcpy(temp->author, root->author);
            strcpy(temp->title, root->title);
            strcpy(temp->ISBN, root->ISBN);
            strcpy(temp->pubDate, root->pubDate);
            free(temp);
            temp = NULL;
            printf("\nBook Record Successfully Deleted\n");
        }
        return root;
    }
    return root;
}

struct node* FindMin(struct node* root) {
    while (root->left != NULL) {
        root = root->left;
    }
    return root;
}
void search(struct node* root, char searchAuthor[]){
    if (root->author < searchAuthor) {
        return search(root->right, searchAuthor);
    }
    else if (root->author > searchAuthor) {
        return search(root->left, searchAuthor);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n\t\t\t--------Searched Book Found--------\n");
        printf("\n\t\t\tAuthor Name \t\t- %s", root->author);
        printf("\n\t\t\tBook Title \t\t- %s", root->title);
        printf("\n\t\t\tISBN \t\t\t- %s", root->ISBN);
        printf("\n\t\t\tPublication Date \t- %s\n", root->pubDate);
        //return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have posted the same question with only minor differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67832726/search-of-binary-search-tree-not-return-to-main-function). The code in your IDE screenshot with the exception does not match the code you've posted here.

Comment: The error you are currently having, I would guess, is you didn't check if the pointer is null. `search` doesn't return anything? `delete` needs work; what is delete returning? I would suggest turning warnings up to a higher level.

Comment: @MOehm Alright i already change the screenshot it's still problem at search

Comment: @Neil I already reedit the snapshot of the problem. It Something wrong at search function

Comment: How can you have `return search(...` when `search` is declared as `void`?

Comment: The screenshot is exactly as before, but you've changed the code. Have you written the insertion and deletion code yourself? Or have you copied it from somewhere without really understanding how it works That's my guess, because searching in a binary tree is quite straightforward.

Comment: @MOehm yuppp firstly im using my code, but i kept getting error, then i decided to take from other reference but still cannot fix... im sorry for my wrong decision to take from other reference

Answer (score 1):

There is much to be improved in your code, but I will just focus on the `search` function here:

- It should handle the case when `root` is `NULL`. By not doing this, you will eventually access `root->left` or `root-right` when `root` is `NULL` which produces an exception.
- Character arrays are not compared like you do it now. Your code is currently comparing pointer values. Use `strcmp` instead.
- Using `return` when the functions type is `void` is contradictory. I would suggest changing the function's return type to `struct * node`, and let the function return the found node, if any, or `NULL` otherwise.

So:

```
struct node * search(struct node* root, char searchAuthor[]){
    if (root == NULL) {
        printf("\n Book not found");
        return NULL;
    }
    int diff = strcmp(root->author, searchAuthor);
    if (diff < 0) {
        return search(root->right, searchAuthor);
    }
    else if (diff > 0) {
        return search(root->left, searchAuthor);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n\t\t\t--------Searched Book Found--------\n");
        printf("\n\t\t\tAuthor Name \t\t- %s", root->author);
        printf("\n\t\t\tBook Title \t\t- %s", root->title);
        printf("\n\t\t\tISBN \t\t\t- %s", root->ISBN);
        printf("\n\t\t\tPublication Date \t- %s\n", root->pubDate);
        return root;
    }
}
```

A final comment on this function: it would be better practice to remove all printing from this function (and other functions), and only do the printing in the main code. This makes your functions independent of I/O matters, which is a good thing.

Comment: but I just notice when it return NULL, all of my records removed from the node. Is there something wrong with my insert_node or just this search function?

Comment: Not with the `search` function, unless you assign the returned value to the root -- which of course you shouldn't do (a search function is never intended to modify the tree). I just focussed on your question. It cannot be the purpose that my answer solves all other problems in your code. If you have another problem, then please ask a question about that via a new question.

Comment: NB: just so you know: Stack Overflow questions should ask *one* question only, so I took the first thing you started with: *"it always mentions that root is nullptr"* (and the screenshot that you provided).